# How can I import ts modules into file and reexport them in another module?

Tags: typescript

I am wanting to split up some of my modules into smaller files, then recombine them for use in other files. How can I do this?

Here's an example of what I would like to do:

/ParentModule/Orders.d.ts

```
export module Orders {
    interface EnteredBy extends Users.Name {
        username: string
        email: string
    }
}
```

/ParentModule/Customs.d.ts

```
export module Customs {
    interface Data {
        drawing: string
        location: string
    }
}
```

/ParentModule.d.ts

```
import { Orders } from 'ParentModule/Orders'
import { Customs } from 'ParentModule/Customs'
export module ParentModule {
    export Orders
    export Customs
}
```

/consumer.ts

```
import { ParentModule } from 'ParentModule'
const enteredBy: ParentModule.Orders.EnteredBy = {}
const data: ParentModule.Customs.Data = {}
```

Comment: Hi Jacob! I personally recommend using an index.ts file in the directory that contains all of these files. For reference check out this medium post: https://medium.com/@balramchavan/smarter-way-to-organize-import-statements-using-index-ts-file-s-in-angular-c685e9d645b7

Comment: This didn't work when I tried it.